# Find, round and replace numbers in a string with regexp

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a string with a number of coordinates each of them having a **15(and 16)-digit** precision. The string looks like this:

`POLYGON ((63.3143749208534741 58.716055226046571,63.406105383130274 58.6706773671378561,63.4052744833828112 58.670392586236112, ...))`

My goal is to output the same string but with coordinates rounded to have strictly **13-digit** precision.

`POLYGON ((63.3143749208535 58.7160552260466,63.4061053831303 58.6706773671379,63.4052744833828 58.6703925862361,...`

I guess it can de done with regular expressions, but I can't understand how to do it.

Could somebody familiar with using **python's re module** explain it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? also, www.regex101.com is a good place to start vetting your regex expressions.

Comment: Regular expressions is _not_ the right tool. Simply split the polygon spec on commas, get the numbers in an array, and rewrite the spec while rounding the numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use lambda func inside re.sub

```
>>> s = 'POLYGON ((63.3143749208534741 58.716055226046571,63.406105383130274 58.6706773671378561,63.4052744833828112 58.670392586236112'
>>> re.sub(r'\d+\.\d{13,}', lambda m: format(float(m.group(0)), '.13f'), s)
'POLYGON ((63.3143749208535 58.7160552260466,63.4061053831303 58.6706773671379,63.4052744833828 58.6703925862361'
```